mvn docker build (Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:set (default-cli) on project myproject)
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:set (default-cli) on project Project version is inherited from parent. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
mvn docker build pipeline error.
set javajdk 17 but not working

Why using such an old version? Current Version is 2.17.1... also I can't really see if this is really related to JDK17 only?
